# Why can't I detect unknown value in Array array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I need to pull data from a site in json format.

I am successfully pulling this data and adding it to the array. I then need to use the data in this string with a for loop.

But sometimes I get the following error. I haven't been able to figure out the reason for this. I'm sending too many requests. (more than 500 in 5 seconds) The code gives an error when adding the total value as "undefined" to the Array array or not. I couldn't solve it.

At least I tried to keep the code running if the total value contains "undefined" but still failed. I keep getting errors.

I would be very grateful for any help. Sorry for my bad english.

**error:**

```
var totalArr = tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total;         
TypeError: Cannot read property 'total' of undefined
```

**code:**

```
request(TRADE_HISTORY_URL + coin, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
  
          tradeCoinHistoryArray = importedJSON.data;   

              for (var i = tradeCoinHistoryArray.length - TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT; i < tradeCoinHistoryArray.length; i++) {

                //error line
                total = tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total;
                //error line


                if(total == undefined){
                  //console.log("continue if total is undefined";
                  return
                }
```

Comment: You would need to check for `undefined` *before* trying to read the property.

Comment: I believe in some cases tradeCoinHistoryArray[i] is empty and you are trying to get an total property of it

Comment: Are you sure that `tradeCoinHistoryArray.length` will always be larger or equal to `TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT`?

Comment: I doubt that the response array is growing infinitely, so the logic `tradeCoinHistoryArray.length - TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT` looks flawed to me and you likely get a negative index. While you could check if `tradeCoinHistoryArray[i]` is `undefined` this would just hide the actual problem you have. But without knowing the API you get the data from, and how you set `TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT` it is not really possible to tell how to solve the problem.

Comment: I know that tradeCoinHistoryArray[i] is always full. To find the error I have printed the incoming data to a .csv file and every time I get the error I can see it has the data.
 @OrhanÖzkerçin

https://prnt.sc/1uj7vrk

Comment: @İsaC. is there any way that `i` is out of scope?

Comment: data was greater than 20 every time I tested it. I'm getting the data from here. Since "https://data.gateapi.io/api2/1/tradeHistory/ETH_USDT" will only use the last 20 data, I used the for loop that way. (tradeCoinHistoryArray.length - TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT). And I tested many times the data was always greater than 20. But this confused me again as I couldn't think of anything else. Maybe because of a problem with the server, the data array can sometimes be less than 20. @t.niese

Comment: I guess it's just like t.niese said. I will not change the length of the array and test it on the server for 1 day and see the result. But as I don't understand, this code sometimes gives an error after 3 hours on the server, and sometimes it works for 3-4 days without an error. @OrhanÖzkerçin

Comment: @İsaC. `And I tested many times the data was always greater than 20.` as long as the API does not give any guarantee about then you shouldn't assume that this is always the case. Doing `tradeCoinHistoryArray.length - TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT)` without verifying that `tradeCoinHistoryArray.length >= TRADE_LAST_TRADE_COUNT` is a bad idea if you don't have that guarantee from the API.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to `tradeCoinHistoryArray[i]` object not being defined.

You can add a check:

```
if (tradeCoinHistoryArray[i] && tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].hasOwnProperty('total')) {
     total = tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total;
}
```

Comment: While this will prevent the error, it likely does not solve the reason why it happens. For certain situations, it is fine to do such a check. But if it is e.g. due to a negative value for `i`, then this is the wrong approach, because it hides an underlying problem.

Comment: True, and that would involve expanding the scope of debugging. This answer would be the starting point for that. To do that an `else` can be added that can log the error and that can aid in further debugging. As you said, there could be error in the way `i` is being set, or the way the `tradeCoinHistoryArray` is being populated.

Answer (score 1):

If your error happening on a line you can't expect to correct an error after executing that line. You need to fix that specific line.

So you may choose to define a static alternate value for that variable, or you should define action in the absence of that value.

This prevents error throw, but undefined will be assigned to `total`.

```
total = tradeCoinHistoryArray[i]?.total;
```

This assigns an alternate value to your total.

```
total = (tradeCoinHistoryArray[i]?.total) ? tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total : 0;
```

If you need to stick es5

```
total = (tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total !== undefined) ? tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total:0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```js
if (tradeCoinHistoryArray[i]) {
    total = tradeCoinHistoryArray[i].total
}
```

Comment: While this will prevent the error, it likely does not solve the reason why it happens. For certain situations, it is fine to do such a check. But if it is e.g. due to a negative value for `i`, then this is the wrong approach, because it hides an underlying problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).